# How set background image and fit that image entire card for card view in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-xml, android-cardview

Here I am trying to fit the entire image as the background for card view. but it takes some space as shown in the picture. I tried `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and `fitXY` and others also but it not responding. In attached image violet color represents empty space that occupied. I need that spaces need to occupied with the background image. Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/voilet">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/application_ads_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/app_ads_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/application_ads_install_button"
            android:layout_width="74dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
            android:background="@color/voilet"
            android:text="@string/application_ads_install"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/application_ads_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/application_ads_image"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.674" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/application_ads_review"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/application_ads_review"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/application_ads_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/application_ads_install_button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.27"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/application_ads_name"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.567" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/application_ads_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Zira"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/application_ads_image"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.176"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[This is **Image** of my output as per my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RDvm.jpg)

Comment: You can set cardview background image with android:background="@drawable/app_ads_background"

Comment: Thanks for reply. Image can't be set as Background Image For a Card View. Even though I made the change as you tell, it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ConstraintLayout`, if you want to make width & height fit to parents, there are two options.

1.Within `layout_constraint` attrs, you **need** to set `0dp` on `layout_width` & `layout_height`

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/application_ads_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

2.If you set `match_parent`, you **don't need** to set `layout_constraint`. If set, it will effect just like `wrap_content`

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/application_ads_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

---

## Update

I write a sample for you, you can check the result like this

[image: Result]

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/voilet">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/application_ads_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/app_ads_background"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/application_ads_install_button"
            android:layout_width="74dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@color/voilet"
            android:text="INSTALL"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/application_ads_review"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="5/5"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/application_ads_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:text="Zira"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you explain more a bit. a little bit confusion on the explanation.

Comment: In `ConstraintLayout`, If yout want a view with width (or height) `wrap_content`, you need to **constraint** position with `layout_constraint`, or if with `match_parent`, you do not need to **constraint** anything. These features depend on `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: FYI, I usually add `layout_constraintStart` & `layout_constraintEnd` and set `0dp` to `layout_width` to match parent horizontally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, What is the value to be added in layout_constraintStart and layout_constraintEnd?

Comment: Sorry, `layout_constraintStart/End` is not a truly attr, it just in shortening and means StartToStartOf, StartToEndOf, EndToStartOf, EndToEndOf .. etc, And the value what we constraint with is `parent`

Comment: Can you please write code for that, even though after it comes.. please refer the image I attached **Link** below the code.

Comment: You want your image fit to cardview right? You can try change the ImageView params with my answer above.

Comment: But it's not working, it remains same.. can write the code fully? please.

Comment: I have Updated answer, please check.

Comment: Sorry, bro even though I put as you said, it not working... I think I need to scale image.

Comment: You can do that as also, but I guess you will face same problem on different resolution ..  Sorry for not help :(

Comment: Thank for your help bro.

Comment: I am just adding `android:scaleX="1.1" android:scaleY="1.1"` to adjust the image,it working,but seems it not good approch.

Comment: You're right. I think it will occur some effects of `blur` with image if it is scaled.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your layout file using my local resource drawable image with ImageView fitXY or matrix scaleType, ImageView picture fits into the card view perfectly. something like the following

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/application_ads_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/a1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

a1 is my local drawable image file, @drawable/a1.
If you still have issue, i will suggest you to check with image/icons dimensions or check the parent view where you are using this layout card.